# Date filter to choose only current month contents

Tags: views

What filter do I need to apply to display only current month content. Am using Drupal 7.

I want to display automatically all content created within the current month.

Comment: You would create a date filter using the node post or create date with a granularity of `month` and then in the relative date field, set it to be equal to `now` and then you should be on your way.

Comment: @Jimajamma That sounds like an answer.